# Rear right side vibration

Tags: dodge, vibration, grand-caravan

1994 Dodge Grand Caravan SE 3.3 ltr. 
Right rear vibration at low speeds. Feels like it vibrates right as it is going to change gears for the last time. It's an automatic, has what appears to be new air shocks. We replaced the wheel bearings, front struts, and left CV joint. The motor and transmission mounts, tires balanced, and an alignment. I thought perhaps it had something to do with the transmission, but I'm not a mechanic. Any thoughts?
We replaced both CV axles, they were bad. Still feel vibration at low speeds. The vibration is at any speed under 45 and it's front wheel drive.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but if its rear wheel drive, check the differential. You may have worn out parts in the joints.

Comment: @Madushan It appears the SE model is All-Wheel Drive (AWD) - Is this correct OP?

Comment: ah right.. but it should still have a differential, right? It's worth to check.